GIO mount SFTP case sensitivity, names converted to lowercase?
I am using GIO to mount an SFTP path where the name contains upper-case characters. This seems to fail, and in the error message the input name seems to have been converted into lower-case.
The full command is gio mount sftp://FOO and the error message is:
gio: sftp://foo/: Connection failed

Notice the change in case.
Is this a bug, or am I missing some standard where the paths must be case insensitive?
I got this case where I had an SSH server configured in ~/.ssh/config and the Host name contained upper-case characters. I was trying to do an SFTP mount to it via GNOME Files. Changing the name used in Host to all lower-case characters solved my problem.
If you want to try for yourself, here is the minimal setup with Docker:
docker run -it --rm ubuntu:24.04 bash

apt-get update
apt-get install dbus ssh gvfs-backends libglib2.0-bin

dbus-run-session bash

gio mount sftp://FOO



Is this a bug, or am I missing some standard where the paths must be case insensitive?

That's not the path; that's the "authority" section of the URL – in other words, the host name field – and host names are defined as case-insensitive in the standard URL format (RFC 3986 §3.2.2), following from its original HTTP-specific definition (RFC 2616 §3.2.3), as they are likewise case-insensitive in DNS (RFC 1035 §2.3.3). Implementations are not required to be case-preserving.
The "path" of the URL (which is case-sensitive) only begins at the slash following the authority (both of your URLs have / as the path).
(Most other host naming systems are case-insensitive as well, including mDNS/Bonjour (RFC 6762 §5 last paragraph) and ARPANET HOSTS.TXT (RFC 810 item 1). Although NetBIOS/WINS names are technically case-sensitive at protocol level (MS-NBTE §2.2.1), they are almost universally forced to upper-case by NetBIOS-using software.)
So I would argue that it is an OpenSSH bug if it matches the Host section case-sensitively.

Perfect! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Yes, just checked again Host FOO and Host foo can both exist in the SSH config. The easiest way for me is not to use any upper case letters anywhere.
